# ¿Cómo reformular los datos de una tabla?

Tags: r, rstudio

¿Cómo puedo ordenar esta tabla de forma que el `año` este en la primer fila y `codigo` en la primer columna y `precip.anual` este para cada `codigo` y cada `año`?

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
    año  codigo   precip.anual
   <dbl>  <int>        <dbl>
 1  1910  87585         663.
 2  1911  87585        1235.
 3  1912  87585        1484.
 4  1913  87585        1173.
 5  1914  87585        1731.
 6  1915  87585         928.
 7  1916  87585         504.
 8  1917  87585         854.
 9  1918  87585         766.
10  1919  87585        1390.
```

Busco obtener esto

```
     | 1910 1911 1912 1913 1914 1915 1916 ........ 2018
-----|--------------------------------------------------
87585| 663. 1235 1484 ..... ......
87590|
87595|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que estás usando `dplyr`, por lo que podrías usar el verbo [`spread()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.3/topics/spread) ("esparcir") del paquete `tidyr` de la siguiente forma:

```
df %>% 
  spread(año, precip.anual)
```

Es decir:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- read.table(text="año  codigo   precip.anual
1910  87585         663
1911  87585        1235
1912  87585        1484
1913  87585        1173
1914  87585        1731
1915  87585         928
1916  87585         504
1917  87585         854
1918  87585         766
1919  87585        1390", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)

df %>% 
  spread(año, precip.anual)

  codigo 1910 1911 1912 1913 1914 1915 1916 1917 1918 1919
1  87585  663 1235 1484 1173 1731  928  504  854  766 1390
```